Ranges of polynomial on $\mathbb{R}^2$
I need to show that range of a nonconstant polynomial on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is either:

$\mathbb{R}$
closed half-line, i.e. $[b;\infty)$ or $(-\infty;b]$ for $b\in\mathbb{R}$
opened half-line, i.e. $(b;\infty)$ or $(-\infty;b)$ for $b\in\mathbb{R}$

There is an example of $x^2+(xy-1)^2$ for which it should be a opened half line. However I do not understand how to show it.The graph for this function is 
I tried to find stationary point. It has one at (0;0). Determinant of hessian is 0 at this point, evaluation of $f(x)$ near 0 concludes that this is saddle point. If we move along y=x for a bit, then function value is slightly decreasing, then it again start to increase.

This edit is based on answer prodived by Dark Malthorp.
He mentioned that for $p(x,y) = x^2+(xy-1)^2$ there is no (x,y) that yields $p(x,y)=0$. Now for range of $p(x,y)$ to be opened we need to show that there is always a (x,y) pair that yields p(x,y) = z for any $z>0$.
For example we have $x = x_{small}$ which is some small value. Then if $p(x,y) = z$, then we have relation $y = \frac {\pm \sqrt{z-x_{small}^2} + 1} {x_{small}}$. This relation is feasible when $z-x_{small}^2 \geqslant 0$. I guess that this means that for every z we can pick x: $|x|<\sqrt(z)$ which is feasible point for p(x,y).

To answer my first question we need to rule out finite intervals and sets that are not intervals.
Finite intervals are also known as bounded intervals. If range of p(x,y) is bounded then it can be represented as $R = \{x|a<x<b\}$ or $R = \{x|a\leqslant x \leqslant b\}$.
In textbook (Dudley "Real analysis and probability") which contains this problem polinomial is given as $\sum_{0 \leqslant i \leqslant k, 0 \leqslant j \leqslant k} a_{ij} x^i y^j$. If we fix y, we can treat this polinomial as $p(x|y=\hat{y})$ or $p(x)$. Then for each $k \in \mathbb{N} \backslash \{0\}$ we can show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}[p(x|y=\hat{y})] = sign(\sum_j(a_{kj} \hat{y}^j)) \times \infty$. Then we can conclude that range of p(x,y) is not bounded.
In order to rule out sets that are not intervals we can use fact that p(x,y) is continious.

What have you tried?

I have tried to find stationary point. It has one in (0;0). det(H) = 0 at (0;0)

You should include your work in the question.

Reading your edits: I think you've got the complete solution now. If I were grading this as a HW question, I would want to see it cleaned up a bit, but the proof is complete if you can cite or prove that the image of a continuous function $\mathbb R ^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is an interval.

Here's how you can show that $p(x,y)=x^2+(xy-1)^2$ has range $(0,\infty)$. Obviously, the upper bound is infinity. Since $p(x,y)$ is a sum of two squares, we certainly always have $p(x,y)\ge 0$.
First, we ask: Can $p(x,y)=0$? In order for this to happen, we would need $x^2=0$ and $(xy-1)^2=0$ simultaneously. The first implies $x=0$, which in turn implies $xy=0$ so $(xy-1)^2=1$. Therefore $0$ is not in the range of $p(x,y)$.
Next: How close to $0$ can we get? Or equivalently, can $x^2$ and $(xy-1)^2$ be small simultaneously? The answer is yes! In order for $x^2$ to be small, we need $x$ to be small. In order for $(xy-1)^2$ to be small, we need $xy$ to be close to $1$. Can you fill in the details to show that for all $z>0$, there exists $(x,y)$ such that $p(x,y)=z$?

To show the general result you are asked to: With the above work, we have examples of polynomials with range $(0,\infty)$. Also $\mathbb R$ and $[0,\infty)$ are obviously possible (take $x$ and $x^2$ respectively). Some trivial modifications can show that $(b,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,b)$ and $[b,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,b]$ also exist as ranges of polynomials. All that remains to show is that there are no other possibilities. This means you must rule out:

Finite intervals
Sets that are not intervals

Do you see how to rule out both of those?

Obviously $x^2+(xy-1)^2\ge 0$.
If $x^2+(xy-1)^2=0$ then $x=0$ and $xy-1=0$ which is a contradiction. So we have $x^2+(xy-1)^2 > 0$.
To see that every positive value is in the range take $t>0$ and set $x=\sqrt t$ and $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt t}$.
